# wordpress rewrite rule 2 subdirectories deep

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to set up a custom WordPress routing the will look like this:

`sitename/books/{book_name}/`

will point to the Page-Book-Single.php file and grab that name in the query_vars

`sitename/books/{book_name}/{article-name}/`

will point to the Page-Book-Article.php file and grab that name in the query_vars

It works for 1 page deep (`sitename/books/{book_name}/`) but with 2 deep (`sitename/books/{book_name}/{article-name}/`) it just returns the same as 1 page deep.

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse26388_rewrites_init' );

function wpse26388_rewrites_init()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'books/?([^/]*)',
        'index.php?pagename=books&book_name=$matches[1]',
        'top' );

    add_rewrite_rule(
        'books/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)',
        'index.php?pagename=books-single&article_name=$matches[1]',
        'top' );

    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse26388_query_vars' );
function wpse26388_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'book_name';
    $query_vars[] = 'article_name';

    return $query_vars;
}

function prefix_url_rewrite_templates() 
{

    if ( get_query_var( 'book_name' ) ) 
    {
        add_filter( 'template_include', function() {
            return get_template_directory() . '/page-books-single.php';
        });
    }

    if ( get_query_var( 'article_name' ) ) 
    {
        add_filter( 'template_include', function() {
            return get_template_directory() . '/page-book-article.php';
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first rewrite rule may take priority, and satisfies all matches.

If you request `sitename/books/{book_name}/{article-name}/` the rule `'books/?([^/]*)'` satisfies it. The rules may have to be:

```
'books/([^/]*)/?$'
and
'books/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?'
```

The first one, forces it to match to the end ($), and there are no following slashes, unless it is a final slash.  The second mandates a slash be between the two segments. This way, if a 2nd slash is in the request (and its not a final character) then its treated as a second value

Comment: Hmmmm that now made `sitename/books/{book_name}/{article-name}/` work as intended but now `sitename/books/{book_name}/` doesnt work

Comment: because, ^ is the start character, not the end. I should have put $ instead and will fix that.

Comment: Perfect!!! What resource can I look at to better understand these rules? Like, what language is it?

Comment: It is called regular expressions and was born out of PERL.  There is a simpler guide here:  http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm
They can be quite complex and quickly become over whelming, but are important to understand in programming.